# How to prevent rerendering of create() while taking snapshot of screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```js
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer'; 
const testdata = TestRenderer.create(<HomeScreen />);
const rootdata = testdata.root;
```

This line of code: `TestRenderer.create(<HomeScreen />)` rerenders our screen which creates issue of lossing props etc. How to prevent rerendering for above line but at the same time we required testdata so that we can perform other operations on that.

Comment: Can you please provide a little bit more information on your issue ?